# I have an input form and I want to drag the result into a table including 2 values

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I have a very simple form that I want to take the result from using html5 and drag and drop it into a space in the table. Then be able to create a new output with the form and repeat the process. I cannot get the information to flow from the form into the table (keeping the values IE: player name and bid) any thoughts? Thanks! Below is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ff.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <script language="JavaScript">
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

section {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
    font-family: veranda, arial;
    font-size: 20px;

}
</style>
<style>
#ffteams {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#ffteams td, #ffteams th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 88px;
    height: 31px;
    <!--ondrop ="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)";-->
}

#ffteams tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#ffteams td:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#ffteams th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    draggable = "true";
}


</style>

<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>Legion of Roar</h1>
</header>

<nav>
<div>
  <form  method="post" action="ff.php" autocomplete="on" name="draftboard">
  <fieldset>
  <legend> Drafting Info</legend>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Player Name.." ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
    draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">

    <label for="position">Position</label>
    <input type="text" id="position" name="Position" placeholder="Position..">

    <label for="Bid">Bid</label>
      <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100">


  <br><br>
        <label for="Team">Team</label>
    <select id="Team" name="Team">
      <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
      <option value="Camren">Camren</option>
      <option value="Marc">Marc</option>
      <option value="Nick">Nick</option>
      <option value="Tony">Tony</option>
      <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
      <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
      <option value="Drew">Drew</option>
      <option value="Matt">Matt</option>
      <option value="Kyle">Kyle</option>
    </select>

  <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<br>

  <aside>

  <label id="Max Bid"><ins>Max Bid:</ins></label>
  <table id="maxbid">
<tr>
    <th>Joe:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Bob:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Tony:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Mike:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Marc:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Camren:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Drew:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Matt:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Nick:</th>
    <th>""</th>
<tr>
    <th>Kyle:</th>
    <th>""</th>
</table>

<br>


</aside>
</nav>

<section>
<h1> Fantasy Football '18 </h1>
<hr>
<table id ="ffteams" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)">
  <tr>
    <th>Joe</th>
    <th>Bob</th>
    <th>Tony</th>
    <th>Mike</th>
    <th>Marc</th>
    <th>Camren</th>
    <th>Drew</th>
    <th>Matt</th>
    <th>Nick</th>
    <th>Kyle</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Person Drafted</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</section>

<!--
<footer><iframe src="https://www.nfl.com/player/mattryan/310/profile" height="200" width="600"></iframe></footer> 
-->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```